# Compile-Errors in the Eclipse Editor of the Tests in src/test/java

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I want to migrate my existing JUnit4-Tests with Powermockito into my Gradle-Project.

```
package test_junit;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import game_editor.lwjgl.impl.LWJGLQuad;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import sr.util.Color;
import sr.util.Position;
import sr.util.Size;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(
{ GL11.class })
public class TestLWJGLQuad
{
 private final int sizeY = 3;
 private final int sizeX = 2;
 private final int y = 1;
 private final int x = 0;
 private final int positionY = 9;
 private final int positionX = 8;
 @Test
 public void teste_print()
 {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(GL11.class);

     LWJGLQuad quad = getQuad();
     quad.print(new Position(positionX, positionY));

     verify();
 }
 private void verify()
 {
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glColor4f(red, green, blue, alpha);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glVertex2f(x + positionX, y + positionY);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glVertex2f(x + positionX + sizeX, y + positionY);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glVertex2f(x + positionX + sizeX, y + positionY + sizeY);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glVertex2f(x + positionX, y + positionY + sizeY);
     PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
     GL11.glEnd();
 }
}
```

And the gradle-File:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

def applicationName = "game_editor"

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

mainClassName = "demo.DemoSzene3Gaming"

def junitversion = '4.+'
def powermockitoversion = '1.+'
def lwjglversion = "2.+"

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl', name: 'lwjgl', version: lwjglversion

   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitversion
   testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: powermockitoversion
   testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: powermockitoversion
 }
```

Gradle builds perfectly, no errors, the Test-Classes have no compile-errors to, all dependencies are in the Build-Path. But in my src/test/java , I cant reference any class of the imported jars in the editor. All references are red underlined.
The usually JUnit-Test don't work neither.

Why is this?